# How to assign dictionary struct to Bindable type from json data

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am using MVVM via Bindable, I am able to assign array using the following code , but how should i assign dictionary data

```
    func getSmallCaseList(id:String) {
        showLoadingHud.value = true
        appServerClient.getSmallCaseDetails(scid: id, completion: { [weak self] result in
            self?.showLoadingHud.value = false
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                guard data.success == true else {
               //error -type of expression is ambiguous without more context
                    self?.caseDetailsCardCell.value = [.empty]
                    return
                }
                self?.caseDetailsCardCell.value = data.compactMap { .normal(cellViewModel: $0 as CaseCardCellVM)}

            case .failure(let error):
                self?.caseDetailsCardCell.value = [.error(message: error?.getErrorMessage() ?? "Loading failed, check network connection")]
            }
        })
    }
```

for more code details [link to gist](https://gist.github.com/abdulKarim002/33532ff5a978f58ed006e9f41b3aa315)

Any help would be really helpful
Thank you

Comment: do you want to assign [string:Any] or [string;yourModel] ?

Comment: @karthik my custom model based on the struct I have implemented, kindly check the gist link for more code in action